# applying jasny input mask on knockout load

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, jasny-bootstrap

I am attempting to apply the jasny bootstrap input mask to a text input that is databound using knockout.  however the datamask does not show up until you click on the input box. I'm not sure why.  I would like the input mask to show up right away.  here is the fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/31938/

here is the html

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-condensed  table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: employees'>
      <tr>
        <td data-bind='text: firstName'></td>
        <td data-bind='text: lastName'></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: phone" data-mask="999-999-9999">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and here is the javascript.

```
function employee(firstName, lastName, phone) {
  this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
  this.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
  this.phone = ko.observable(phone);

}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.employees = ko.observableArray("");
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  loaddata();
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});

function loaddata() {
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee("Bob", "Jones", "7174569876"));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee("Mary", "Smith", "3457892435"));
  mymodel.employees.push(new employee("Greg", "Black", "3557689800"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing the input mask on document load, after your Knockout bindings have been applied:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loaddata();
    ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
    $('.form-control').inputmask({
      mask: '999-999-9999'
    })
});
```

Be sure to remove your data-mask attribute as well.

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vL59q8e1/1/)